# SetTimeout not firing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying a new performance enhancement technique.
I'm trying to update the Backbone.collection in batches.
I will call loop function recursively with setTimeout.
Does anyone know why this SetTimeout not working?
Please let me know.

```
 var length = this.collection.length - 1;
 var self = this;
 loop();
 function loop(l){
   console.log('Getting into loop func');
   var start = +new Date();
   var len = l || length;
  do{
    console.log('Processing', len);
    process(len)
  }while (--len >=0 && +new Date() - start < 50);
 console.log('--Getting to if--'); 
 if (len >= 0) {
   console.log('------------', len);
   setTimeout(function(){loop(len)}, 25); 
 }
function process(i){
  console.log('process', i);
  self.collection.at(i).set('descStat', descStatus);
}
}
```

Comment: does your console bring up anything?

Comment: and your function process is inside your function loop, is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, all console.log in my code work, but not inside the setTimeout.

Comment: Yes, so ideally in my SetTimeout I will call loop() function recursively.

Comment: try upping the timeout value as 25 is low and browser might think it is spam or an attack.

Comment: I don't like this kind of questions: "X doesn't work". `setTimeout` is an standard function in JavaScript. How the... won't work! I would re-rephrase this and other questions to "I'm trying to achieve X and setTimeout isn't reached so far, what am I doing wrong?"........

Comment: @Buck3y3, I don't think that would do it.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't ever be getting to the setTimeout call, because your while loop doesn't terminate until `len >= 0` is false.

Comment: That's not true, there are two conditions, len and milleseconds --len >=0 && +new Date() - start < 50

Comment: If what you're saying is true, then I should never see console.log('------------', len); I do see it.